# spry accordion tab height effecting content

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion, spry

I have created a simple spry accordion on this test page http://www.rubbuk.com/test/index.htm

Link : "Choose your location"

Inside the `.AccordionPanelTab` div I have created my own div to style the location drop down. Doing this has somehow created a blockage in the content section. I've tried the simple things of heights etc but they didn't seem to work.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? In the `#map` div apply the following css styles `position: absolute; z-index: 2000;`. Also, what do you mean by "blockage"?

Comment: When you press "Choose your location" the accordion drops down but the content should span the full width but for some reason there is a white box the width of the div class="location_drop" that is blockage this

Comment: Try to remove the css rule `overflow: auto` from the .AccordionPanelContent div.

Comment: As an alternative, you can also try adding `float: left` to the .AccordionPanelContent div.

Comment: Sorted.... thank you. overflow: auto done the trick. great help thank you